# Unable to get error stack trace or error log while using php-fpm + nginx

Tags: nginx, php, php-5.5

I am using php-fpm 5.5.9 along with nginx 1.4.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have installed them using apt-get package manager. I am unable to get a stack trace of the error that my index.php script encounters in error log as well as on the browser. I searched and implemented a couple of solutions from stackoverflow and other articles but none of them worked for me. Here is my nginx conf along with my php-fpm conf file. Please help me out if I am  doing any silly mistake.

**Nginx Configuration:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        # With php5-fpm:
                #try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_connect_timeout  600;
        proxy_send_timeout  600s;
        proxy_read_timeout  600s;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
```

**PHP-FPM Configuration:**

```
error_log = /tmp/php5-fpm.log
```

**PHP-FPM pool Configuration:**

```
catch_workers_output = yes 
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool.log.slow
listen = 127.0.0.1:7777

php_flag[display_errors] = On 
php_admin_value[error_log] = /tmp/fpm-php.www.log 
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = On
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly couldn't find reasonable solution without using PHP xdebug module.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

It should install the module configuration, may have to restart php-fpm afterwards though.

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Once that was installed I could finally get a stack trace out from php5-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration is says that the `error_log` file is in `/etc/...` However you could just be looking in the wrong place.

Did you anyway check the default error log location? Usually it should be:
`/var/log/nginx/*` - there is a `nginx_error.log` file in there. Possibly other log files as well.

Also note that the PHP-FPM and [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure) config configurations differ in syntax. 
Check if you have such an error anywhere. It may be parsed wrongly and thus your errors.

Check file permissions for the error log. Is *nginx's running user* able to Write there?